Why do Jews believe Jesus was NOT the messiah?
It's a known fact that Jews don't believe that Jesus was the messiah. The reason for this(as stated) in everywhere I searched are the prophecies in Jewish bible about the messiah that Jesus doesn't fit in. Reading the wikipedia

Judaism affirms that Jesus did not fulfill the messianic prophecies by 

ushering in an era of universal peace (Isaiah 2:4),
building the Third Temple (Ezekiel 37:26–28),
and gathering all Jews back to the Land of Israel (Isaiah 43:5–6). 

Jews believe the Messiah will be a direct (blood) descendant of King David through Solomon on his father's side and will be born naturally to a husband and wife (Genesis 49:10, Isaiah 11:1, Jeremiah 23:5, 33:17; Ezekiel 34:23–24).

What's striking to me is that these verses, prophecies do NOT actually say that it would be messiah that would fulfill these phopecies. My reasoning are as follows:

While Isaiah 2:4 mention universal piece that would happen at some day, It doesn't say that this universal piece would be brought by Messiah. It says that God would bring it and there's no indication of Messiah doing this.
Ezekiel 37:26–28 has the same problem. It's not saying that Messiah would build the temple. It says that God will make it such that people would have his sanctuary.
Isaiah 43:5–6 again has the same problem. It's God that will bring people back to their land. It's not Messiah that would achieve that.
Genesis 49:10 doesn't really say that messiah would be the descendant of King David.
Isaiah 11:1 kind of talks about the shoot coming from Jesse's roots but where do you get the idea that this messiah would be born naturally to a husband/wife ?
Jeremiah 23:5 has again the same problem.

So either I am reading these verses completely out of context or something might be wrong with my understanding. I'd appreciate if you can shed some light on each verse and why it's true what wikipedia is saying. Thank you.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Could you clarify, is your question about Jesus or about why Jews interpret these verses as messianic?

Regarding Ezekiel 37:26–28: You should probably start at least two verses earlier: "My servant David shall be king over them..."

Why would a heretic be the Messiah?

No christian is christian because of bible verses. The bible only becomes important to a christian once he is into that man, and the feelings such as spirituality, relief from trauma, gratitude to fellow christians (or simple peer pressure) that he gains from that belief. We will not debate you on bible verses, you will lose but you won't be able to hear it so it's a waste of everyone's time. Come back if you are here not to tell us how we are wrong, as a lawyer, but here to ask serious questions, from a position of re-opening the case, as a judge

R' Tovia Singer has over a thousand videos on this exact topic. Go watch ten of them and come back with a serious question.
